# Lucene .NET Update data

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I started use Lucene several days ago, but in debug my solution I found one trouble in Lucene. For try solve this problem I create new custom project and started test different solutions, but after 2 days of searching solution with Lucene I surrender...

My problem :

I create one custom class, create standard array of this class. 
Create Document objects and index it by IndexWriter. Its all works fine. Search working great. But when I try to update any document by using IndexWriter.UpdateDocument and say it update document with, for example, index '5', its create new document with id = 5. And finally I have 2 documents with id=5, and old, and new. If in constructor of IndexWriter 'true' in replace id, so when I update it same code its save only 1 updated document, and remove all indexed before. Exactly, I can't update all base all time, because my base is large (about 600 internet resources on my constructor), I need update only changed data (replace it new), and save indexed before. May be some one know what I doing wrong?

P.S. Sorry for my english.

```
class mydoc
{
    public string id;
    public string name;
    public string content;

    public mydoc(string ID, string Name, string Content)
    {
        id = ID;
        name = Name;
        this.content = Content;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Create data array...");
        mydoc[] docs = new mydoc[11];
        docs[0] = new mydoc("0", "Name0", "tet 5");
        docs[1] = new mydoc("1", "Name1", "aaaa text");
        docs[2] = new mydoc("2", "Name2", "and me test ");
        docs[3] = new mydoc("3", "Name3", "I am new tes 3");
        docs[4] = new mydoc("4", "Name4", "I am new tes 4");
        docs[5] = new mydoc("5", "Name5", "I am new test 5");
        docs[6] = new mydoc("6", "Name6", "I am new text 6");
        docs[7] = new mydoc("7", "Name7", "I am new text 7");
        docs[8] = new mydoc("8", "Name8", "I am new text 8");
        docs[9] = new mydoc("9", "Name9", "I am new text 9");
        docs[10] = new mydoc("10", "Name10", "I am new test 10");

        Console.WriteLine("index processing...");
        var dir = new DirectoryInfo("tmp");
        FSDirectory fsdir = FSDirectory.Open(dir);
        Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29);
        IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(fsdir , analyzer,true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);

        for (int i = 0; i < docs.Length; i++)
        {
            writer.AddDocument(Convert(docs[i]));
        }
        writer.Optimize(true);

        writer.Close(true);

        Console.WriteLine("index done !");

        IndexReader reader = IndexReader.Open(fsdir, true);
        for (int i = 0; i < reader.MaxDoc;i++)
        {
            Document doc = reader.Document(i);
            Console.WriteLine("id = \"{0}\", Name = \"{1}\", Context = \"{2}\"", doc.Get("ID"),doc.Get("Name"),doc.Get("Content"));
        }
        reader.Close();

        // Update custom base
        IndexWriter updater = new IndexWriter(fsdir, analyzer, true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
        updater.UpdateDocument(new Term("0"), Convert(new mydoc("0", "New name 0", "prosto obitr test")), new StandardAnalyzer(Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30));
        updater.UpdateDocument(new Term("1"), Convert(new mydoc("1", "New name 1", "prosto obitr test")),new StandardAnalyzer(Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30));
        updater.UpdateDocument(new Term("2"), Convert(new mydoc("2", "New name 2", "prosto obitr test")), new StandardAnalyzer(Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30));
        updater.UpdateDocument(new Term("3"), Convert(new mydoc("3", "New name 3", "prosto obitr test")), new StandardAnalyzer(Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30));
        updater.UpdateDocument(new Term("4"), Convert(new mydoc("4", "New name 4", "prosto obitr test")), new StandardAnalyzer(Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30));
        updater.UpdateDocument(new Term("5"), Convert(new mydoc("5", "New name 5", "prosto obitr test")), new StandardAnalyzer(Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30));
        updater.UpdateDocument(new Term("6"), Convert(new mydoc("6", "New name 6", "prosto obitr test")), new StandardAnalyzer(Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30));
        updater.UpdateDocument(new Term("7"), Convert(new mydoc("7", "New name 7", "prosto obitr test")), new StandardAnalyzer(Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30));
        updater.UpdateDocument(new Term("8"), Convert(new mydoc("8", "New name 8", "prosto obitr test")), new StandardAnalyzer(Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30));
        updater.UpdateDocument(new Term("9"), Convert(new mydoc("9", "New name 9", "prosto obitr test")), new StandardAnalyzer(Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30));

        updater.Optimize();
        updater.Close(true);

        reader = IndexReader.Open(fsdir, true);
        Console.WriteLine("New updated data:");
        for (int i = 0; i < reader.MaxDoc; i++)
        {
            Document doc = reader.Document(i);
            Console.WriteLine("id = \"{0}\", Name = \"{1}\", Context = \"{2}\"", doc.Get("ID"), doc.Get("Name"), doc.Get("Content"));
        }

        Console.ReadKey();


        Console.WriteLine("search processing...");
        string query = "test";
        fsdir = FSDirectory.Open(dir);
        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(fsdir, true);
        Console.WriteLine("Searching phrase \"{0}\"", query);
        List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> results = find(query, searcher);

        searcher.Close();
        fsdir.Close();

        Console.WriteLine("Results:");
        for (int i = 0; i < results.Count; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                // Display founded id
                Console.WriteLine(results[i].Value);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\n\rDone !");
        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    static List<KeyValuePair<int,int>> find(string query, IndexSearcher searcher)
    {
        var parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, new[] { "Name", "Content" }, new SimpleAnalyzer());
        var score = searcher.Search(parser.Parse(query), 99).ScoreDocs;
        var docIDs = score.Select(x => new KeyValuePair<int, int>
            (
                x.Doc, int.Parse(searcher.Doc(x.Doc).Get("ID"))
            )
            ).ToList();
        return docIDs;
    }


    static Document Convert(mydoc doc)
    {
        var document = new Document();
        document.Add(new Field("ID", doc.id, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
        document.Add(new Field("Name", doc.name, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
        document.Add(new Field("Content", doc.content, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));

        return document;
    }
}
```

In this case doc[10] just disapear from index.
if in

```
IndexWriter updater = new IndexWriter(fsdir, analyzer, true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
```

'true' replace to 'false', it create new documents instead replace old.

updater.commit() also did not help.

Comment: Can you try reducing your program down to a minimum so that it is easier for others to help with debugging, reading code, etc.?

Comment: I dont know what i can reduce there, but i can expalain.
First i create array with custom class obkects (mydoc).
After add it to index by convert each mydoc to Document (Lucene object) and index it by IndexWriter. Next i display all exist Documents in Lucene index.
After i making changes by using IndexWriter updater.UpdateDocument. For see what changes done in Lucene index i again Display all stored Documents in index. And after doing search by word "test" in documents, and Display result documents ID, that in Field "Content" have word "test". 
Its all.

Comment: I don't have knowledge of IndexWriter but I can see a few things in your code that could be the problem. (1) in your updater you only have 10 documents and not 11. Doc[10] is not in the list. (2) also, you seem to create new documents instead of calling old ones and update them. I might be wrong.

Comment: In that case, I update only 10 and not 11, because in out I must get 11 docs, because 11 was indexed first, 10 updated and 1 doc must be old data. in display I get only 10 updated. That mean while update it remove ALL stored data and add new. Yes, it can work successful, but I cant index 100 Mb data every 10-30 mins. It very expensive in perfomance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. My fault was in not correct understanding of type Term in:

```
IndexUpdater.UpdateDocument(Term term, Document doc);
```

Its need to create new instance of Term like this (in my case):

```
updater.UpdateDocument(new Term("ID", "5"), Convert(new mydoc("5", "New name 5", "simple new test text")), new StandardAnalyzer(Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30));
```

Where in Term constructor field "ID" is my unique field with no index flag and "5" is text of old value field "ID" in old document in index.